# How to select between bright spots in a continuously updating image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, object-detection

Suppose I have some function:

`find_spots(image) -> list[tuple[x, y]]`

that takes a greyscale image as its input, and using OpenCV/some other image processing library, returns a list of tuples of bright spot coordinates sorted by brightness.

I want to develop a `select_spot()` function that allows a user to select which spot they want to track for subsequent images.

The problem I'm having is that each new image can potentially return a new list of bright spots, so if we rely on the index at which any spot occurs in the list in order to track it, we may lose the desired spot as the list changes.

Any clean solutions to this problem? Or any other way to select and track a particular bright spot within an image (while calculating/keeping track of all other spots in case a user wants to change the spot they are tracking).

Additionally the coordinates of all spots may change as the camera that takes these images moves, so we still want to select the desired spot even though, for example, it may show up on the other side of the image.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to construct a KD Tree (scipy has this built-in) and choose the closest (X, Y) from the tree. It's hard to say if this works in practice though since if the spots are too close together or move too much between frames you'd lose track. However, the second point applies to any processing method (imagine you have 2 lists of random spots, how can you find the same spot in both lists?). This also requires the number of spots to be relatively small if you want to do this in real time (i.e. less than 1000).

Comment: If that solution doesn't work, you might have some luck with SIFT feature detectors as long as the "spots" look distinctly different. It's honestly hard to say when there are no concrete examples or specifications.

Comment: you might find normalizing the coordinates to a range of 0 to 1 helpful (min x = 0, max x =1, min y=0, max y=1).